# Posting question on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

1. How do I ask a question on Stack Exchange? I don't see any "ask question" button.
2. On which one should I post my question, Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow?

Comment: Looks like you found the "ask question" button, to ask this. You would normally pose your question on the relevant site for which it is on topic, so if it is the sort of software development question that relates to a piece of source code, you'd ask it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), if it was about improving your photography, you'd ask it [on the relevant StackExchange site](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), etc.

Comment: You need to access the individual StackExchange sites; see http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 3):

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) is the portal to all the sites in the Stack Exchange network, as it clearly says in the page:

> Stack Exchange is a fast-growing **network** of 91 question and answer sites on diverse topics from software programming to cooking to photography and gaming. We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on the most important topics in each area of expertise. From our core of Q&A, to community blogs and real-time chat, we provide experts with the tools they need to make The Internet a better place.

You can't ask a question in this portal, you have to go to a specific site of your choice and ask your question there.

If your question is related to programming and satisfy the conditions in the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) then by all means, go ahead and ask it on Stack Overflow.

Good luck, and happy programming!